# How to read an XML file into C buffer removing additional whitespaces?

Tags: c, xml, file-io

I have an xml file whose contents are

```
<Body>
      <Head1>Some Heading</Head1>
      <Body1>
             <K1>V1</K1>
             <K2>V2</K2>
      </Body1>
</Body>
```

when I read this file into a buffer(which is a char array in C) using fread similar to this code: [Reading the whole text file into a char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747086/reading-the-whole-text-file-into-a-char-array-in-c)
I obtain a c buffer which contain whitespace. is there a way the additional whitespace which are coming on the left in the XML file be removed by loading into the buffer?

EDIT:
I earlier used fgets to read the file line by line, removed the whitespaces on the left and concatenated. it worked, but is there a better way?

Comment: You might consider using an [xml parser library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399704/xml-parser-for-c) and not worry about extra spaces.

Comment: why invent the wheel a second time? use libxml2 and all is done for you. programming is about reusage