# Reading a text flle "line by line" into an array in c

Tags: arrays, c, file, line

I want to modify this function  to read files line by line into an array.

Currently this function will read the **entire** contents of the file into one single array index.

The function in question is "loadfile".

I am not sure where to start in-order to accomplish this.

Here is the code + the output in the terminal.

```
void *loadfile(char *file, int *size)
{
    FILE *fp;
    long lSize;
    char *buffer;

    fp = fopen ( file , "rb" );
    if( !fp ) perror(file),exit(1);

    fseek( fp , 0L , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell( fp );
    rewind( fp );

    /* allocate memory for entire content */
    buffer = calloc( 1, lSize+1 );
    if( !buffer ) fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);

    /* copy the file into the buffer */
    if( 1!=fread( buffer , lSize, 1 , fp) )
      fclose(fp),free(buffer),fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);

    /* do your work here, buffer is a string contains the whole text */
    size = (int *)lSize;
    fclose(fp);
    return buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

printf("hello\n", "%s");

int i;
char* array[6];

for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
  array[i] = loadfile("sample_in.txt", 1);
  //printf("Content: %s", array[i]);
}


printf("ARRAY_INDEX_0: %s", array[0]);
    }
```

OUTPUT: (the entire contents of the file)

```
ARRAY_INDEX_0: pwd
ls -l -a -F
ps
pwd -L -P
ls
```

Comment: Please take a look at this post as it should answer your question already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747128/2016565

Comment: Why do you pass 1 to `loadfile`? It is supposed to be an `int*`. This line: `size = (int*) lSize;` changes the value of a passed argument. You probably meant to do `*size = (int) lSize;` to pass the size back to the caller. But since you pass 1 to the function, your app will crash.

Comment: FWIW, given `fp = fopen ( file , "rb" );`, your call to `fseek( fp , 0L , SEEK_END);` is [undefined behavior in strictly-conforming C code](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268): "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream ..."  Using `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file is not portable and relies on your operating system's specific implementation details, so you might as well do `struct stat sb; fstat( fileno( fp ), &sb ); long long file_size = sb.st_size;`  Even Windows supports that.

Comment: Should it solve my problem? @AndreasHinderberger , that post deals with reading the whole file , new lines and all I believe

Comment: @JimRhodes The reason I did that is because I don't exactly know how the program works, as it's something I got from the internet.