# How can I load a whole file into a string in C

Tags: c, string, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to get file's contents in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174531/easiest-way-to-get-files-contents-in-c)

My program reads files that span over many lines. I would like to hold the content of a file in a single string.

I don't know the number of lines of my file before execution, however I have fixed a line size to MAX_LINE_LEN.

How can you do that?

Comment: this has been asked at least one hundred times, I guess

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The function `fread()` doesn't care about line breaks. The following code reads the contents of `input_file_name` and saves them to the array `file_contents`:

```
char *file_contents;
long input_file_size;
FILE *input_file = fopen(input_file_name, "rb");
fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);
input_file_size = ftell(input_file);
rewind(input_file);
file_contents = malloc(input_file_size * (sizeof(char)));
fread(file_contents, sizeof(char), input_file_size, input_file);
fclose(input_file);
```

You can only make a string of this array if `input_file_name` contains the `\0` character. If it does not, change the last three lines to:

```
file_contents = malloc((input_file_size + 1) * (sizeof(char)));
fread(file_contents, sizeof(char), input_file_size, input_file);
fclose(input_file);
file_contents[input_file_size] = 0;
```

Comment: +1 but change `long long` to `size_t`, or at least use `long`, the actual return type of `ftell`.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the observation. @rahmu: That means that, if `sizeof(long) == 4`, the above will only work for files smaller than 4 GiB.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the last line be `file_contents[input_file_size + 1] = '\0';` ?

Comment: @Chris: No. An array `a` of size two has the elements `a[0]` and `a[1]`. Likewise, the last element of an array `file_contents` of size   `input_file_size + 1` is `file_contents[input_file_size]`. As for `0` vs `\0`, using a character constant or its integer representation makes no difference.

Comment: Using this on certain linux system files, input_file_size is returned as 1 block, regardless of content. A solution is to terminate the string using the number of bytes read by fread:

`bytes_read = fread(...);
file_contents[bytes_read] = 0;`

Comment: There seem to be security issues related to using fseek/ftell for determining the file size: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file

Answer (score 3):

1) figure out the size of the file with `fstat`.

2) alloc a zeroed buffer of this length + 1

3) use `fread` to read the file contents into the buffer

Comment: 4) Add a null terminator at the end. (EDIT: Okay, I see you said "zeroed buffer", but why spend all the time zeroing every byte if you overwrite it anyway? Not that it matters in real life, but still.)

Comment: fair point. although i'd argue that the time taken to zero a buffer is negligible compared to the I/O overhead unless the file is huge. The user could just zero the last byte.

Comment: If you use `calloc`, on most OSes it'll be the same speed as `malloc` because the OS does something in the background to make sure memory is zeroed-out (to make sure `calloc(8 * getpagesize())` doesn't take forever), but it is, of course, no guarantee.

Comment: @James: Absolutely, that's why I said it doesn't matter in real life. I'm just so used to working in an environment where you count every cycle that I couldn't help but nitpick :)

Comment: What is the size of the file changes between `fstat` and `fopen`?