# How can i split a txt file which contains ;s in C?

Tags: c

I want to split this txt file. How can I split it from semicolons? It must be in C.

x.txt:

```
stack;can;3232112233;asdasdasdasd
```

Result

```
string[0]=stack
string[1]=can
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    int j, i=0; // used to iterate through array

    char userInput[81], *token[80]; //user input and array to hold max possible tokens, aka 80.

    printf("Enter a line of text to be tokenized: ");
    fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);

    token[0] = strtok(userInput, ";"); //get pointer to first token found and store in 0
                                       //place in array
    while(token[i]!= NULL) {   //ensure a pointer was found
        i++;
        token[i] = strtok(NULL, " "); //continue to tokenize the string
    }

    for(j = 0; j <= i-1; j++) {
        printf("%s\n", token[j]); //print out all of the tokens
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read complete file into a buffer using [`fread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174531/easiest-way-to-get-files-contents-in-c/174552#174552) and then use [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) with `;` as a delimiter and keep saving your strings.