# replace bytes in file c

Tags: c, file-io

I got some code and I want improve it to find and replace bytes in file
so
I want to find all origbytes in FILE and then replace it with newbytes
then save file, I know how to open, write and save, but hot I can find bytes in char?

```
 FILE* file;
 file = fopen("/Users/Awesome/Desktop/test", "r+b");
 int size = sizeof(file)+1;
 char bytes [size];
 fgets(bytes, size, file);
 for (int i=0; i<size; i++){ 
     char origbytes  []  = {0x00, 0x00};
     char newbytes   []  = {0x11, 0x11};
     if (strcmp(bytes[i], origbytes)) //Here the problem
     {
         fseek(file, i, SEEK_SET);
         fwrite(newbytes, sizeof(newbytes), 1, file);
     }
 }
 fclose(file);
```

Comment: As a reminder, if you have answers to your questions that are good, you should accept one.

Comment: `sizeof` does **not** give the size of files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strcmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strcmp.html) is for string compare and not character compare. Two characters can be compared directly

```
if ( bytes[i] == origbytes[something] )
```

Also you you should not apply `sizeof()` on a file pointer to determine file size. You should seek to the end of file using `fseek` and then query `ftell` [except for binary files](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+file). For binary files, use something like [`fstat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fstat.html)

One more thing to note is that `fgets` returns much before the EOF if it sees a newline. Hence in your code, you may not read entire file contents even after doing the changes that we suggested. You need to use `fread` [appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174531/easiest-way-to-get-files-contents-in-c)

Comment: Good answer. Only a small correction: actually [the link to cert](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+file) you gave recommends against using `fseek/ftell` for anything except new `fseeks` in the same file, both for binary and text files. So it's best to use `fstat` to get file size in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are null terminated in the C standard library. Your search data is effectively a zero length string. You want `memcmp` instead.

```
memcmp (&bytes [i], origBytes, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly sizeof(file) + 1 just returns you the size of a pointer + 1. I don't think you need this for the size of the file. Use this: [How do you determine the size of a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c)
Then since you compare bytes (more or less smae as char) you simply compare using =

Answer (score 0):

you can use fseek and then ftell functions to get the file size, not sizeof.

Comment: That's more accurate than `sizeof`, but less efficient. Better to just query the file system for the size directly.