# How to copy text to array of characters in C

Tags: c

I would like to copy text from text file to

How to copy text file to string in C?

```
 FILE *file; 
file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
```

and I assign it in variable like that

```
    // char P[] = "Content from File";
```

Comment: Use the fgets() function to read from a text file up to the next newline.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174531/easiest-way-to-get-files-contents-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple ways this can be done. My personal favourite is to use `fread()` like this:

```
// Open the file the usual way.
File *file = fopen(filename, "r");
if(!file) exit(1); // Failed to open the file.

// Figure out the length of the file (= number of chars)
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
long int size = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

// Create the char-array and read the file-content.
char *P = malloc(size * sizeof(char)) // Allocate enough space.
if(!P) exit(2); // Failed to allocate memory.
fread(P, sizeof(char), size, file); // Read the file content.
```

---

Here's an explanation as to how it works:

- `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)` Takes the file-stream `file`, and sets the stream-position to the end of the file (indicated by `SEEK_END`) with no offset (hence the `0`). You can read more about this std-library function [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm).
- `ftell(file)` takes the file-stream `file` and returns the current stream-position (which we have previously set to be the end of the file, so this will give us the length of the entire file). This value is being returned as a long int. You can read more about it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_ftell.htm).
- Now we have to set the stream-position back to the beginning, so that we can later read the file. This is being done with `fseek()` again, this time giving it the position-argument `SEEK_SET`. This tells it to jump back to the start of the file.
- We can now allocate our text-buffer, in your case called `P`. (After a malloc, don't forget to check if you actually got a valid pointer back!)
- Finally, we can read the file! `fread()` takes four arguments. The first one is the buffer to which we are going to write. This is the `P` char-array in your case. The second argument, `sizeof(char)`, tells `fread()` what size the individual elements are going to be. In our case, we want to read characters, so we pass it the size of a character. The third argument is the length of the file, which we have previously determined. The last argument is the file-stream which should be read. If you want to read up on `fread()`, you can do that [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm).