# How to read data from a txt file?

Tags: c

I have a .txt file with
"./a.out,file.txt,./a.out2,file2.txt"

How can I store "./a.out", "file.txt", "./a.out" and "file2.txt"?

I was trying to use fgets() and sscanf().

```
while (fgets(buffer, 80, fp) != NULL) {
    sscanf(line, "%s, %s, %s, %s\n", a, b, c, d);
    printf("a = %s\n", a);
    printf("b = %s\n", b);
    printf("c = %s\n", c);
    printf("d = %s\n", d);
}
```

[but if i print them out, i will read the whole inline into char* a]

Comment: `%s` reads whitespace delimited strings. Use `%[^,]` for comma delimited, instead. Also, be sure to check the return value of `sscanf` before assuming that all 4 strings were actually filled in.

Comment: Why are you scanning `line` if `fgets()` is filling `buffer`?

Comment: regarding: `sscanf(line, "%s, %s, %s, %s\n", a, b, c, d);`  1)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values)   any returned value other than 4 indicates an error occurred.  2)  the `%s` needs to have max characters modifier that is one less than the length of the input array.

Comment: the `%s` stops inputting when a 'white space'  is encountered.  Per your question, the input file has no white space between the data elements.  Rather there is a comma between the data elements.  strongly suggest reading the whole line with `fgets()` then using `strtok()` for the extraction of each data element

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.\

Comment: `fgets(b, s, fp); sscanf( ., "%s")` is an alternate spelling of `gets()`.  There's no point using a size in fgets if you immediately throw it away with sscanf.

Comment: regarding; `sscanf(line, "%s, %s, %s, %s\n", a, b, c, d);`  DO NOT place '\n' on the end of the format string.  Because this will consume all trailing white space and will not return until a non-white space is encountered.

Comment: @WilliamPursell,  the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the language several years ago.

Comment: @user3629249 "not return until a non-white space is encountered." is a concern for `scanf()`, not `sscanf()` as the _null character_ stops the scan.  The trailing `\n` is not needed,  a waste of some CPU cycles, but not a functional problem,

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, gets() is no longer in the language.  I am beginning to believe that raw `"%s"` should be completely disallowed for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following question for how to read in a file to a string: [How to read the content of a file to a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174531/how-to-read-the-content-of-a-file-to-a-string-in-c). Then you can use strntok() with the delimiter ",".